# Geodesic velocity vector field pullback on given coordinate chart

Tags: geometry

The geodesic curve $x(t)$ on a manifold $(\mathcal{X}, g)$ corresponds to a curve evaluation $\varphi(u(t))$ on the coordinate chart $(U, \, \varphi)$. Additionally, since the velocity vector $\dot{x}(t)$ has a constant norm along a geodesic curve, it is irrelevant which variable $t \in [0, 1]$ to evaluate the curve. The velocity vector $\dot{x}(t)$ is given by product of jacobian matrix by chart coordinates velocity vector i.e. $J_\varphi \dot{u}$.

The question is: **How to evaluate its pullback $\varphi^*\dot{x}$?**

I am not able to prove to myself it is true, despite theory statements. May you enlighten me?

Comment: Geodesics on a sphere are great circles,  For [geodesics on an ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid) (a stretched sphere), the equivalent statement is usually not correct

Comment: I do not believe your "known fact" is correct. Where did this come from?

Comment: Spheres are the most symmetric objects I can imagine of. A straight line across the circle must map back to a straight line in its parametrization chart.

Comment: I edited the answer for good comprehension.

Comment: To reiterate Henry's and DavidK's comments: Are you asking whether/claiming that plane sections through the center of a non-spherical ellipsoid are precisely the geodesics, and/or that great circles are images of Euclidean lines under geographic coordinates? (Both are Not True.) The edits are not clarifying the intent (for me), however....

Comment: My question is about the pullback $\eta^*\dot{c} \in T_u U$ to coordinate chart $(U, \varphi)$: what is the pullback of a geodesic for a sphere and/or ellipsoid?

Comment: Please, read $\eta$ as $\varphi$ (I make (many) mistakes). I edited once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the comment, "My question is about the pullback $\varphi^{*} \dot{c}$ [...] to coordinate chart $(U, \varphi)$: what is the pullback of a geodesic for a sphere and/or ellipsoid?

---

For definiteness, and attempting to utilize concepts and notation from an earlier edit of the question, let's agree spherical coordinates on the unit sphere are defined by the mapping
$$
\varphi(u, v) = (\cos u\sin v, \sin u\sin v, \cos v).
$$
Geographically, $u$ is longitude, $v$ is colatitude, and while the mapping is smooth on the $(u, v)$ plane, it only defines local coordinates (in the sense of differential geometry) in regions where $\sin v \neq 0$, i.e., in open subsets of strips $k\pi < v < (k + 1)\pi$ for some integer $k$.

A path $c(t) = (u(t), v(t))$ in the plane induces a path $\gamma := \varphi \circ c$ on the sphere. It appears the questions are,

1. If $\gamma$ is a geodesic on the unit sphere, what is $\dot{c}(t)$? (Strictly speaking, tangent vectors do not pull back under a mapping; presumably the question is to find or describe the velocity $\dot{c}(t)$, i.e., the pushforward of the velocity $\dot\gamma$ under $\varphi^{-1}$.)
2. If $\lambda_{1}$, $\lambda_{2}$, and $\lambda_{3}$ are distinct positive real numbers and $E$ is the ellipsoid parametrized by
   $$
   \psi(u, v) = (\lambda_{1}\cos u\sin v, \lambda_{2}\sin u\sin v, \lambda_{3}\cos v),
   $$
   and if $\gamma$ is a geodesic on $E$, what is $\dot{c}(t)$?

For the first, it sounds as if the attempt was to show $c$ is a constant-speed line in the $(u, v)$-plane. Whether or not that interpretation right, the mathematical situation is different. A geodesic on the unit sphere is a constant-speed great circle. If we write $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t), z(t))$, then there exists a unit vector $n = (A, B, C)$ such that
\begin{align*}
  0 &= Ax(t) + By(t) + Cz(t) \\
  &= A\cos u(t)\sin v(t) + B\sin u(t)\sin v(t) + C\cos v(t).
\end{align*}
Where $\sin v(t) \neq 0$, we can write
$$
A\cos u(t) + B\sin u(t) = -C\cot v(t)
$$
and solve for $u(t)$ in terms of $v(t)$ (and $(A, B, C)$), but the solution is "usually" not a constant-speed line in the $(u, v)$-plane. That observation, in turn is no geometric surprise: A spherical coordinate curve is a great circle if and only if it is a longitude line $u = \text{constant}$ or the equator $v = 0$.

---

For question 2., matters are worse: As Henry noted and linked in the comments, the geodesics of a non-spherical ellipsoid do not have an explicit description, and they are planar sections if and only if $E$ is symmetric in the sectioning plane.

Comment: I thank you sincerely (what would be an insincere thank!? :'P) for your answer!

Comment: You say the used definition of pullback is not strictly correct. What is, in your opinion, the concept equivalent definition in euclidean canonical space?

Comment: Tangent vectors push under arbitrary smooth mappings, forward, covectors pull back. For a diffeomorphism (such as a coordinate chart), the pushforward by the inverse "looks like" a pullback, but strictly speaking is not. In general there _is_ no pullback of a vector by a smooth mapping, nor a pushforward of a covector.